# Prove that if $M$ is simply connected and $H^2(g) = 0$, then $M$ is symplectomorphic to an adjoint orbit.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, group-actions, symplectic-geometry

*A manifold $M$ is said to be homogeneous if there exists a transitive action $G ↷ M$. Let $(M,ω)$ be a homogeneous symplectic manifold, i.e., there exists a transitive and symplectic action $G ↷ M$. Prove that if $M$ is simply connected and $H^2(g) = 0$, then $M$ is symplectomorphic to an adjoint orbit.*

**Here $g$ is the lie algera of $G$ (the action group) and $H^*(g)$ is the  Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology of the lie algebra $g$.**

I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand and prove this statement. Specifically, I would like to know the steps and reasoning behind the proof. Could you please provide a detailed explanation or point me to any relevant resources that can help me grasp this concept?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 4):

The point is that under your hypothesis, there exist a moment map $J=M\to g^*$, and this map is equivariant. This is called strongly hamiltonian in the literature.

Let $\bf X$ the space of hamiltonian vector fields on $M$. The map $C^{\infty }(M)\to \bf X$ is the map which sen a function $f$ to the corresponding hamiltonian vector  field is a Lie algebra homomorphism (for the Poisson bracket) with kernel the constant fonction : hence it is a central extension, and define a certain class $\omega \in H^2(\bf X)$. This map is surjective as $X$ is simply connected.

The fact that the action is strongly hamiltonian means that the map $g\to \bf X$ lifts to a Lie algebra homomorphism $g\to C^{\infty}(M)$

The obstruction to lift this Lie algebra homomorphism is a certain element in $H^2(g)=H^1(g,g^*)$, which is zero in your case.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand why you are considering $X$ simply connected. Isn't $M$ the simply connected space? Also how would it imply that the map taking smooth real functions on $M$ to hamiltonian vector fields being surjective? Wouldn't that be a consequence of the definition?

Comment: I have a couple of thing that I dont understand in your rasoning, firsit, why does that moment map exist? (I know that every symplectic action is hamiltonian if $H^1(g)=H^2(g)=0$). Second, how does your answer lead me to conclude that $M$ is sympletomorphic to $G/G_m$? Can you elaborate more you point? Thanks!

Comment: To lift hamiltonian vector fields, one assumes $H^1(M)=0$.

Comment: To make sure that this lift can be preserve bracket, one needs that $H^2(g)=0)$. This implies equivariance of the moment map.  Then equivariance implies that the image oof an orbit (ie $M$) is an orbit (a co-adjoint orbit)